TikZiT figure fails to appear
I am trying to use the TikZiT application to draw a graph. I've created a folder for my project, into this folder I copied the tikzit.sty file downloaded from the TikZiT official site. I've created a tikzstyles file using TikZiT GUI and added the line \input{../../Documents/Study_Materials/AIM/Algorithms-I/algorithms-i.tikzstyles} into my document. Finally, I've created a graph and saved it both to figdfs.tikz file inside the main folder and a file with the same name in the figures subfolder. However, the code
\begin{equation}
  \tikzfig{figdfs}
\end{equation}

fails to produce a picture, instead producing this:


did you mean to write \tikzfig{dfsfig}? In your question, the .tikz file is called dfsfig, but you call figdfs.

I did indeed mean to write dfsfig, but that does not change a thing. In my code, the name was correct. I've modified the question to remove any confusion.

As your posted code can't compile, nobody can check or try your code(s) ...

What exactly can't compile, and what should be able to?

@DaigakunoBaku What MS-SPO means is that no one can reproduce your issue without having access to a minimal working example that we can run on our computers to obtain the same result as you. Try expanding the snippet into a complete document, and include the separate files as separate code blocks.

@Jasper, thank you. If you'd write your 3 lines of code to a file, say dia.tex, and compile from a terminal via pdflatex dia.tex ... it will complain quite a lot ... // Once you resolved that, by starting with a \documentclass ... , it will complain about the unavailable figdfs.tikz ... so there's almost nothing we can do.
